CiviCRM upgrade 5.64.0 to 5.69.3 crashes on Joomla 5.1 - any hints?
I just tried upgrading (Install from Directory' method) to latest CiviCRM 5.69.3
It proceeded OK until it got to the end, when it threw a joomla FatalError.
It killed the civiCRM installation, (rest of Joomla seemed OK) and I had to restore from backup.
So back to running 5.64.0 and looking at installing 5.64.4 security patch only.
The docs are not really specific on this... is it necessary to install earlier upgrade versions?
do I need to do 5.65, 5.66, 5.67, 5.68 to get to 5.69?
Doc site implies otherwise: "Select the latest currently available CiviCRM tarball for Joomla."
Also, the downloads page has TWO Joomla packages Joomla and Joomla-ALT - what is the difference??
I am running Joomla 5.1.2
PS: got these errors in the httpd log:
[Sat Aug 10 13:03:30.131391 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 32621:tid 140423217510144] [client 63.22.63.13:47704] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.1.db517c6df60afb0bfca58hh8.log
[Sat Aug 10 13:03:30.153286 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 32621:tid 140423200724736] [client 63.22.63.13:47716] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/upload/delete-this-4G2gUFo9jz
[Sat Aug 10 13:03:30.169522 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 32621:tid 140423183939328] [client 63.22.63.13:47726] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/custom/delete-this-zsdHFN9GHF
[Sat Aug 10 13:03:48.487728 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 32621:tid 140423133583104] [client 63.22.63.13:42846] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.1.db517c6df60afb0bfca58hh8.log
[Sat Aug 10 13:03:48.498964 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 32621:tid 140423108404992] [client 63.22.63.13:42850] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/upload/delete-this-UXVy4sMXBC
[Sat Aug 10 13:03:48.510058 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 32621:tid 140423100012288] [client 63.22.63.13:42858] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/custom/delete-this-aRVdiet38p
[Sat Aug 10 14:32:36.349317 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 32621:tid 140423259473664] [client 63.22.63.13:60860] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.1.db517c6df60afb0bfca58hh8.log
[Sat Aug 10 14:32:36.360164 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 32621:tid 140423217510144] [client 63.22.63.13:60876] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/upload/delete-this-0TgCMINaiL
[Sat Aug 10 14:32:36.370353 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 32621:tid 140423234295552] [client 63.22.63.13:60884] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/custom/delete-this-WndKs935pr
[Sat Aug 10 14:32:41.152848 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 32621:tid 140423192332032] [client 63.22.63.13:46036] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.1.db517c6df60afb0bfca58hh8.log
[Sat Aug 10 14:32:41.163857 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 32621:tid 140423183939328] [client 63.22.63.13:46038] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/upload/delete-this-dYKjAPGiw4
[Sat Aug 10 14:32:41.174491 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 32621:tid 140423167153920] [client 63.22.63.13:46042] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/custom/delete-this-2VVYZE5MsO
[Sat Aug 10 15:15:40.226307 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 34357:tid 140514493957888] [client 63.22.63.13:37668] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.1.db517c6df60afb0bfca58hh8.log
[Sat Aug 10 15:15:40.241472 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 34357:tid 140514477172480] [client 63.22.63.13:37680] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/upload/delete-this-5zpM5tFEg4
[Sat Aug 10 15:15:40.252698 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 34357:tid 140514460387072] [client 63.22.63.13:37684] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/custom/delete-this-L9Bqiv9T48
[Sat Aug 10 15:15:51.783964 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 34357:tid 140514638108416] [client 63.22.63.13:47572] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.1.db517c6df60afb0bfca58hh8.log
[Sat Aug 10 15:15:51.798219 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 34357:tid 140514552706816] [client 63.22.63.13:47578] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/upload/delete-this-TDxBBybc81
[Sat Aug 10 15:15:51.808185 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 34357:tid 140514535921408] [client 63.22.63.13:47586] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /[joomla root]/media/civicrm/custom/delete-this-nM7uALwt3Z

Welcome to SE!

... is it necessary to install earlier upgrade versions? do I need to do 5.65, 5.66, 5.67, 5.68 to get to 5.69?

No, you can go straight to the latest version.

Also, the downloads page has TWO Joomla packages Joomla and Joomla-ALT - what is the difference?? I am running Joomla 5.1.2

One has most of the files in a second zip file inside the first.  We're in the process of changing to only have a single package but you can use either one - the end result is the same.
The situation on Joomla 5 is messy at the moment.  To upgrade, I have needed to remove the psr/log files from the zip before trying to install since there is a conflict between the version of that package in Civi vs Joomla 5.
It's probably best to get yourself on to https://chat.civicrm.org, go to the Joomla channel and reply to the post on there that points to this question.

Although these are probably not the cause of your problem, but two tips that I always do when upgrading CiviCRM on Joomla:

always do it on a staging installation first (I use devilbox to create local copies of all sites I maintain, with Akeeba and a little script I can restore a site with one command)
remove the previous CiviCRM source in administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm (Joomla packages are just extracted on top, so if any files are removed in the new version they will not be removed from your file system)

...-joomla and ...-joomla-alt are just different packaging. I think it has to do with archives within archives. Just pick one.
